# Using Apache Spark for processing plain text from/to Elasticsearch

Tags: scala, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

I want to utilize Apache Spark to preprocess text data from an Elasticsearch index. With [ElasticSearch Hadoop](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) I am retrieving the index to Apache Spark. I get an RDD of the type: RDD[(String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef])]

The first element looks like: 
document: (String, scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef]) = (file:document_id, Map(created -> Mon Jan 20 11:50:35 CET 2014, modified -> Fri Oct 23 12:46:40 CEST 2015, indexed -> Fri Mar 25 18:05:37 CET 2016, mimetype -> application/pdf, **content -> Plaintext of the document**)

Now the critical parts are the processing of the above content field with a NLP toolkit and storing the results in Elasticsearch. 
The first part works great. I found a similar question [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222559/simplest-method-for-text-lemmatization-in-scala-and-spark) using the StanfordCoreNLP (unfortunately Spark does not provide this itself and I cannot retrieve the tokens from Elasticsearch directly). As a result I get the tokens for each document as RDD[Seq[String]] but I don't know how to get this into Elasticsearch.

Obviously I need an outputRDD that connects documents with the associated tokens. Something like: Map("document_id_1" -> "Tokens for id_1", "document_id_2" -> "Tokens for id_2").
Maybe someone wants to provide a hint how to get there or has a better idea to solve the problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd._
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline._
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util.Properties 

object Stemming {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf() .setMaster("local[*]") .setAppName("SparkLemma")
            .set("es.nodes", "hadoop-m:9200" )
            .set("es.write.operation", "upsert")
            .set("es.mapping.id", "id")
          val esIndex = "elastic/documents"
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Read data from ES
    val esRDD = sc.esRDD(esIndex)
    val id:RDD[String] = esRDD.map(_._1.toString)
    val content:RDD[String] = esRDD.map(_._2("content").toString)
    val plainText: RDD[(String, String)] = id.zip(content)
    val stopWords = sc.broadcast(scala.io.Source.fromFile("stopwords.txt").getLines().toSet).value

    def createNLPPipeline(): StanfordCoreNLP = {
        val props = new Properties()
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")
        new StanfordCoreNLP(props)
    }

    def plainTextToLemmas(content: String, stopWords: Set[String], nlp: StanfordCoreNLP) : Seq[String] = {
        val doc = new Annotation(content)
        nlp.annotate(doc)
        val lemmas = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
        val sentences = doc.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation])
        for (sentence <- sentences;
            token <- sentence.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation])) {
            val lemma = token.get(classOf[LemmaAnnotation])
            if (lemma.length > 3 && !stopWords.contains(lemma)) {
                if (lemmas.isEmpty) {
                    lemmas += id += lemma.toLowerCase
            }
                else {
                    lemmas += lemma.toLowerCase
                }
            }
}
lemmas
    }
    val lemmatized: RDD[Seq[String]] = plainText.mapPartitions(strings => {
        val nlp = createNLPPipeline()
        strings.map{case(id, content) => plainTextToLemmas(content, stopWords, nlp)}
    })

def writeTokensToES(row:Seq[String]): Map[String,String] = {
    val tokens = row.drop(1).mkString(" ")
    Map("id" -> row.head, "content" -> tokens, "last-run" -> getDate())
}
val outputRDD = lemmatized.map(row => writeTokensToES(row))
EsSpark.saveToEs(outputRDD, esIndex)
sc.stop()
}
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you might have two questions: 1) how to get your extracted tokens (lemmatized) back into ES; 2) how to join the data in your token RDD (lemmatized) to ES doc ids. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks Taylor for your response.

Comment: You're absolutely right; I don't really know how to deal with this Tuple2 RDD I get from Elasticsearch. As you can see above I use this zip function to combine the ID RDD with the content RDD. I seriously doubt that this is an efficient way. Fortunately, I was able to insert the tokens back into ES. I modified the ArrayBuffer such that the first element is the document_id.

Comment: You can save original id when you generate your lemmatized RDD instead of dropping it (hence you'll get RDD[String,Seq[String]] )